# SSL is required to authenticate keycloak behind traefik

Tags: spring, spring-boot, keycloak, traefik

I have the problem that my spring application with the keycloak adapter give me this warning:

> SSL is required to authenticate. Remote address IP is secure: false, SSL required for: EXTERNAL .

The keycloak address is with https

Every request to my backend is blocked with a 401 Error and this warning in the console.

Keycloak is behind a reverse proxy: **traefik**

I also tried to remove the headers with traefik:

```
- traefik.http.middlewares.sso.headers.customrequestheaders.X-Forwarded-For=
- traefik.http.middlewares.sso.headers.customrequestheaders.X-Forwarded-Proto=
- traefik.http.middlewares.sso.headers.customrequestheaders.X-Forwarded-Host=
- traefik.http.middlewares.sso.headers.customrequestheaders.X-Real-IP=
```

Edit: I can fix it with `keycloak.ssl-required = none` and also in the admin panel but is this safe?

Answer (score 1):

`keycloak.ssl-required = none` is definetly not a secure work around. There is Keycloak doc, which describe how to configure it properly:

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#_setting-up-a-load-balancer-or-proxy

Comment: of course but is't a false positive because of the load balancer? The requests are HTTPS, I think the load balancer mess up with the headers.

Comment: @jakob that's not false positive! You are saying that Keycloak should generate and require TLS. If you have TLS offloading (= your "because loadabalancer" use case), then there are headers to tell Keycloak which protocol was used to reach load balancer (that [standard] mess up with `X-Forwarded-Proto` header), so Keycloak will accept also plain HTTP connection from LB. Just follow documentation.

Comment: Backend ---HTTPS---> Traefik ---> HTTP ---> Keycloak 
But why is it not safe? Traefik and KeyCloak are on the same server?

Comment: @jakob Sorry, this is not a chat/forum. Generally, don't use "keycloak.ssl-required = none" (see OIDC spec to see why TLS is required) and configure headers on LB according Keycloak doc - then you can use TLS offloading with any loadbalancer/reverse proxy (Traefik, Nginx, Apache, F5, AWS ALB, ...) without affecting Keycloak functionality.